# Where are the questions tagged "featured" shown?

Tags: support, tags, question-lists, moderator-tags

The excerpt for [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) used in this meta site is the following:

> A special moderator-only tag to mark important meta discussions. A question with this tag can be seen on the main site in a special sidebar in the questions list and when viewing individual questions.

Looking in SO, I see a "Featured" tab under "Questions," but that tab lists all the questions for which has been offered a bounty.
Where are the questions tagged [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) shown?

Comment: I felt very stupid reading this question without reading the quote. :P

Comment: (Some more details about MSO in a comment to Grace's answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) does not possess this improved functionality on Meta Stack Overflow. This is because it lacks the "Visit Meta" sidebar element, depicted below.

[image: Image of English Stack Exchange, with the Visit Meta element on the right sidebar]

This sidebar element provides links to hot Meta questions. The questions selected are based on the weekly hot questions and the front page questions on the Meta site, but [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) has the highest priority and will be listed above any such.

As this Meta site does not possess an inhouse ad, instead the tag serves a normal functionality of grouping important announcements, for those who pay attention to them. But it's probably not used all that much because of their limit.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then questions tagged "featured" are also [shown on the home page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/59f3m.png) of MSO itself, along with [the highest voted questions tagged "faq"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106598/mso-faq-sidebar-shows-same-question-twice). Also note "featured" [is removed from the post view after 30 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92194/i-re-added-the-featured-tag-but-it-doesnt-show/92218#92218), though it then still shows in the latest post revision. Maybe it then also still shows in the list of tagged questions?