# I re-added the featured tag, but it doesn't show

Tags: support, tags, meta, moderator-tags, featured-tag

I initially posted [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/general-tagging-practices) (on a meta site where I was and still am a moderator) with the `featured` tag. The tag since then expired, and just now I tried adding it back. I used the [“secret `edit tags` button”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88151/what-is-the-reason-for-removing-the-retag-link-for-users-with-full-editing-rights/88152#88152), which may or may not matter. Now the question is in a strange state: it doesn't have the `featured` tag

[image: no featured tag in the question view]

but the tag is there in the question editor!

[image: featured tag in the editor]

(I've refrained from further editing the question, in case investigation is needed.)

Comment: There's only [one revision](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/412/revisions) on that post. I rather suspect the tag isn't actually *removed* when it expires, but merely hidden (or perhaps removed from denormalized data somewhere). So neither the expiration nor your edit actually modified the original post... I wonder, can you simply remove and then re-add the tag manually?

Comment: Seems related (reoccurring): [Editing a site-meta post with an expired featured tag requires me to restore it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243086/editing-a-site-meta-post-with-an-expired-featured-tag-requires-me-to-restore-it)

Comment: Since there is no firm confirmation that this behavior has actually disappeared, I'm moving to leave this open.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The way in which this is no longer reproducible is that [auto-removal of the featured tag is now an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266470/566903), and this question was discussing the strange behavior of the tag being removed without creating a revision to mark its removal.

Comment: @pppery Ah, right, missed the answer (you don't see it in the Close Votes queue). Voted to close.

Comment: @pppery This affects posts that were magically unfeatured before it was an edit. So AFAIK this is still reproducible. The change only means that it won't affect any more posts than it does now.

Comment: @Gilles I don't believe there are any such questions remaining anymore. If there are, report them on the per-site meta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Shog noted, no revision is created when the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag is removed from a question after 30 days.

(we do this because if we did not, every meta would be littered with dozens of forgotten "featured" questions over time.)

Thus, when you edit the revision, the tag is still there -- although it does not exist on the current view of the post. So in order to get it to appear, you'll need to make some other change to the tags.

Comment: I see. The UI is a bit confusing (when I clicked on the tag editor, `featured` wasn't there, and afterwards it was there, so the UI was telling me I'd added it). Technically a UI bug, but for a mods-only feature and only in rare cases.

Comment: (This [also affects non-moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128531/the-moderator-tag-featured-must-be-present-but-it-wasnt-there-in-the-firs), @Gilles & Jeff. And those then even can/MUST re-feature a post when editing... But this has been reported and surely will be fixed.)