# When and why is the [featured] tag removed by the Community user?

Tags: support, community-user, featured-tag

I've found that the Meta (moderator only) tag [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) is automatically [removed](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/586/revisions) by the [Community ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user. So, I want to know when and why is the tag [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) is removed by this user?

Is there any mechanism for this removal or is there simply a specified time period after which the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) is automatically removed by the Community user?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92194/i-re-added-the-featured-tag-but-it-doesnt-show), it is automatically removed after 30 days. In this case, it apparently took a week longer.

Jeff Atwood says this is because:

> if we did not, every meta would be littered with dozens of forgotten "featured" questions over time.

Here, [Shog9 says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310910/295232) after one month:

> As of today, MSE featured questions work the same way as featured questions on any per-site meta: they are featured until the tag is manually removed, something newer bumps 'em off, or the system automatically strips the tag (roughly 1 month after it is added).

Which one is it? [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1363411/meta-questions-unfeatured-by-community) seems to suggest Shog9 is correct (especially the 'roughly' part). The data shows that **the script that removes expired [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tags runs once a week on Saturdays at around 0:00 UTC, and removes tags that were placed 30 days ago or longer**. This means that if the tag is added on a Thursday or Friday, it will take an additional week for it to eventually get removed (as 30 days before Saturday is a Thursday). With the SEDE site switcher you can easily check other metas.

[image]

Apparently, it doesn't run on Stack Apps, perhaps because it's not a true Meta site; [What's the next Script/App/Library of the Month?](https://stackapps.com/q/9281/34061) has been featured continuously since January. (And yes, we could use more submissions, but I digress...)

Comment: The roughly is probably because it checks that is older than 30 days every X amount of days.