# Featured questions are not shown network wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, community-bulletin, featured-tag

Currently, there are three questions tagged with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) here on Meta Stack Exchange. Usually, when there is a post with this tag, it is visible throughout the network on the Community bulletin or bulletin board with "Featured on Meta" right side of our page. But these questions are not shown on the bulletin board.

[image: bulletin board on Movies]

There should be a section Featured on meta but this is absent. Above is a screenshot from Movies&TV Stack Exchange but I haven't seen it on other sites as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no idea why this was done; it never made sense and caused more'n a few mistakes and wasted hours in the past when folks forgot that it worked that way.

As of today, MSE featured questions work the same way as featured questions on any per-site meta: they are featured until the tag is manually removed, something newer bumps 'em off, or the system automatically strips the tag (roughly 1 month after it is added).

Answer (score 4):

No bug. As Shog said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/152859):

> Additionally, up to 2 recent (**post created in the past two weeks**) featured posts from Meta Stack Exchange will appear in the community bulletins of all sites

Emphasis is mine: **created** in the last two weeks.

All [three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310321/brace-yourselves-the-gdpr-is-coming) [featured](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305560/2018-monthly-product-team-updates) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310061/electronic-opt-out-correcting-miscommunication-and-additional-questions-answer) currently here on Meta Stack Exchange were *created* more than two weeks ago, and only edited/retagged with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag recently, which is not relevant for the purpose of the per-site community bulletin.

I would totally support a feature request asking to change that logic, for example show questions *tagged as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) on MSE in the last two weeks*.

Comment: If that is the case, what is the point of adding the tag? The tag implies that the post is very important and should reach larger audience. It should be shown throughout the network irrespective of the post age. That feature should be useful.

Comment: @NogShine better ask Shog...

Comment: @NogShine https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7002319#7002319