# Bulletin board doesn't show 3 featured questions at a time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta, community-bulletin, featured-tag

We know that questions with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) are visible throughout the network in the bulletin board i.e., The Yellow Box. Currently there are 3 [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions out of which only two are visible on the side bar. New question with this tag i.e.,  [An Update to our Community and an Apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/357396) is not visible to network wide audience.

On Science Fiction and Fantasy which has both hot meta posts and [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) from per site meta.

[image: Bulletin board from Science Fiction and Fantasy stack Exchange with featured questions and hot meta posts]

After two featured questions from Meta Stack Exchange, rest of the space is taken up by per site meta questions.

Following is from Movies & TV  which doesn't have a featured question from their per site meta.

[image: Bulletin board from Movies and TV stack Exchange with no featured questions from per site meta]

Even though there is space for all question to get featured, third question is not shown.

This bug report is related to my old bug with a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [Featured questions are not shown network wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310880/357396)

Shog9 made changes to show featured questions throughout the network irrespective of the date the tag is added or the date they are created.

Despite this change, the number of questions shown in the community bulletin is limited to 2 only. The goal of the tag is to make the network users aware of the changes happening on Meta Stack Exchange but that is not fulfilled. Due to this the goal of addition of the tag will not be achieved.

Can this be fixed to show all the featured questions in the bulletin board?

Comment: The change he made did not change *how many* featured questions can be shown. That is still 2, maximum. He only removed the time limiting blockade.

Comment: @animuson Is there any reason [I see three](https://gyazo.com/052cafeaf1fa1fa884a84d71ce0ff7a2)? Is that because I'm on MSE?

Comment: @animuson Yeah. Shog9 made only that change. But I see all the three featured questions now. Is this solved?

Comment: @Script47 If I understand correctly, it is important whether you are on a main site or a child meta site because behaviour on the sites is different.

Comment: A quick note: the number of featured questions from Meta.SE was temporarily raised to three from two a couple weeks ago.