# Why did the SE team unfeature the recent announcement about font changes?

Tags: discussion, meta, featured-tag

I noticed that [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/942994) about the change of fonts was once featured in Meta, but now, it seems that it is no longer featured. How long do Meta posts stay featured?

---

I'm not asking about the technical reason why the post is no longer featured, which is what [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281797/when-and-why-is-the-featured-tag-removed-by-the-community-user) is asking about. Instead, what I'm asking is why the SE team chose to remove the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag from the post and when they remove the tag from posts. Those are not answered there.

Comment: Until there is something more important to feature

Comment: Generally, it's removed when there's a new featured post about to be made soon. In this case, it was [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364556/the-future-of-community-promotion-open-source-and-hot-network-questions-ads?cb=1).

Comment: The accepted answer to the duplicate says "they are featured until the tag is manually removed, something newer bumps 'em off, or the system automatically strips the tag (roughly 1 month after it is added)".

Comment: @PolyGeo Not a duplicate. To me, it seems that this question is asking about SE policy on their removing the featured tag from posts they feature, not on the system's removal of a featured post from the bulletin.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I see nothing in this question to suggest it’s asker thinks the featured tag was removed by other than the situations already covered by the answer to its duplicate.

Comment: It was unfeatured after 13 days, which [isn't too far from the average](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364953/295232).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [@Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/295232):

> **Additionally**, up to two [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts from [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeatured%5D+is%3Aquestion+created%3A14d..) will appear in the community bulletins of *all* network sites (including Meta Stack Exchange, but not per-site metas). These are also filed under "Featured on Meta". Note that these will appear in addition to all of the other stuff listed above, so the list of community bulletin posts might appear longer than usual, depending on the individual site circumstances.

As the quote says, only two featured posts from this site can appear in the bulletin.

On May 18th, a new post [The future of Community Promotion, Open Source, and Hot Network Questions Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/295232) became featured and for the other slot, the slightly older post [Testing three-vote close and reopen on 13 network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364007/295232) was deemed more important than the one about the font change. Stack Exchange staff is welcome to go into more details about this decision, but I'm not sure they will bother to share them. (Nor would I blame them for that.)

Under some rare cases, the team does bump the max up to 3, but as that clogs up the community bulletin box for other communities, this is extremely rare.

Comment: Not much to add. Unless something is only valid for a short period of time (outages) it's pretty normal that the reason something is unfeatured is generally due to needing the space for something else. There's generally not much more to it.