# Meta questions have been unfeatured without creating revisions, causing problems when editing

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, revisions-list, featured-tag

This started out as a Stack Apps question, because my script was trying to repair the image in the DBA.Meta post [So what's with the hats thing?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/868/67785), and encountered the following error while trying to call the [question edit operation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-question):

> {"error_message":"The moderator tag 'featured' must be present.","error_name":"write_failed","error_id":407}

The supplied value for `tags` is `discussion`, i.e. the only current tag. I wasn't sure why the API is trying to compare the tags against a previous revision ... except that when I checked the [revision list](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/868/revisions), there is no notice of the post being un[featured]. I can't find any evidence in the [timeline](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/868/timeline) or in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.dba/query/1690972) either. So this must be a (historic) bug in the unfeature script.

It's not just the API which has problems with this; via the UI, it's not possible (unless you're a moderator, I guess) to edit the post yourself:

[image]

I have no idea how widespread this bug is, but perhaps one could figure that out via a SEDE query.

Comment: I think this is another case where there's a mismatch between the tags that are actually visible on the post and the tags listed on the post in the database...? Anyway, I've removed the invisible [featured] tag from that post for you for now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I re-added the featured tag, but it doesn't show](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92218/282094) or this deleted question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128531/the-moderator-tag-featured-must-be-present-but-it-wasnt-there-in-the-first