# MSO faq sidebar shows same question twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

On MSO's sidebar right now there's a small list of frequently asked questions. The first and last one right now are both [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange). This is likely to be a bug.

[image]

[Speculation](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/721480#721480): The question appears twice because it is tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and voted highly, and [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), which pins questions to the sidebar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your speculation was correct, it's a simple fetch of [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions trying to get 10, if that fails it then gets 10-*n* [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions.

In the next build it won't do this so blindly, you shouldn't see dupes anymore.

Comment: Just curious: is this MSO specific? (It seems things are different on [TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), which right now [shows two links](http://i.stack.imgur.com/niVTm.png), out of which [one](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/wrong-close-reason-shown) seems to be just a regular post.)

Comment: Ah, Jeff explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128531/the-moderator-tag-featured-must-be-present-but-it-wasnt-there-in-the-first/128533#comment351031_128533).